# jQuery Mobile: call JavaScript Function ReferenceError: Can't Find Variable

Tags: jquery-mobile

My code will work if use this:

```
for(i=0; i<listUsers.length; i++){
   if(listUsers[i] != usr){
      $( "#listHisUser" ).append('<li><a href="#hist_cont" onclick="getChatContent()">'+listUsers[i]+'</a></li>').listview('refresh');
   }
}

function getChatContent(){
   alert("data");
}
```

but if I change it to this:

```
for(i=0; i<listUsers.length; i++){
   if(listUsers[i] != usr){
      $( "#listHisUser" ).append('<li><a href="#hist_cont" onclick="getChatContent('+listUsers[i]+')">'+listUsers[i]+'</a></li>').listview('refresh');
      }
}

function getChatContent(data){
      alert(data);
      alert("data");
}
```

It gets error: `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: tqminh at file:///android_asset/www/index.html#hist:1` where `tqminh` is a listview item which I clicked.

```
<!-- History -->
<div data-role="page" id="hist" data-title="HISTORY">
   <div id="a" data-role="header" data-theme="b">
   <h1 style="text-align: left;font-size: 20px">History Chat</h1>
   </div>       
   <div data-role="content" data-inset="true">
   <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="c">
   <li><a href="#" onclick="getChatContent('tqminh')">tqminh</a></li>
   </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function parameter is not rendered as string. try to replace

```
<a href="#hist_cont" onclick="getChatContent('+listUsers[i]+')">'+listUsers[i]+'</a>
```

with

```
<a href="#hist_cont" onclick="getChatContent(\''+listUsers[i]+'\')">'+listUsers[i]+'</a>
```